# Convert SQL Query to query in C#

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I've currently got the SQL code below:

```
 WITH region_list
 AS (SELECT r.StateProvinceRegion, 
            r.CafeId,
            s.Longitude, 
            s.Latitude, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.StateProvinceRegion
            ORDER BY s.Longitude DESC) AS row_no
     FROM CafeAddress r
     inner join Restaurant s on s.CafeId = r.CafeId
 )
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID,
        StateProvinceRegion, 
        Longitude, 
        Latitude            
 FROM region_list
 WHERE row_no = 1;
```

How would I go about adding this query? In my method below I've implemented something similar but I don't understand how to add the WITH clause in.

```
public VersionResponse GetCafeRegion()
{
    var regionList = from cafeAddress in _context.CafeAddress
                     join cafe in _context.Cafe on cafeAddress.CafeId equals cafe.CafeId
                     select new { cafeAddress.StateProvinceRegion, cafeAddress.CafeId, cafe.Longitude, cafe.Latitude };

    return new VersionResponse()
    {
        Data = regionList
    };
}
```

Comment: Is that Entity Framework or Linq? Either way add the correct tag - its nothing to do with ASP.NET Core itself.

Comment: Two accounts? and yup I'll remove the tags

Comment: Rather add the correct tags... you posted this exact question under your James account a couple of hours ago...

Comment: And its not C# you are converting to, its Linq (I think - or EF).

Comment: This looks like a highly optimized query leveraging specific T-SQL features. (`WITH`, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))`, ...)

I don't know if it can be converted to LINQ that produces the _exact_ same SQL...

Comment: That'll be my partner

Comment: Why not convert the query to a procedure and execute that from C#?

Comment: @SteveC so something like CREATE PROCEDURE <Database Schema>.<Procedue Name>
AS
BEGIN
   WITH region_list....
END

Comment: Yes and then read the results

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code once.

```
public VersionResponse GetCafeRegion()
{
    var CafeAddress = new List<CafeAddress>();
    var Cafe = new List<Cafe>();

    var regionList = from cafeAddress in _context.CafeAddress
                        join cafe in _context.Cafe on cafeAddress.CafeId equals cafe.CafeId
                        group new { cafeAddress.StateProvinceRegion, cafeAddress.CafeId, cafe.Longitude, cafe.Latitude } by cafeAddress.StateProvinceRegion into g
                        select g; 

    List<object> finalResult = new List<object>();
    int index = 1;

    foreach(var gg in regionList)
    {
        var groupRecord = gg.OrderByDescending(x => x.Longitude).FirstOrDefault();

        finalResult.Add(new
        {
            ID = index++,
            groupRecord.StateProvinceRegion,
            groupRecord.CafeId,
            groupRecord.Latitude,
            groupRecord.Longitude
        });
    }

    return new VersionResponse()
    {
        Data = finalResult
    };
}
```